# vagrant: Error getting repository data for C7.6.1810-base, repository not found

Tags: vagrant, centos7, dcos

I'm following below steps to create mesos -

https://dcos-e2e-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dcos-vagrant-cli.html

when I run the command `minidcos vagrant create ./dcos_generate_config.sh --agents 0` I get below error.

```
Error getting repository data for C7.6.1810-base, repository not found
==> dcos-e2e-918351cd-9d88-47c6-9b72-b2f5194302fc-master-0: Checking for guest additions in VM...
Error creating cluster.
Try "minidcos vagrant doctor" for troubleshooting help.
```

How to resolve that error?

Comment: Have a look here: https://jira.mesosphere.com/browse/DCOS_OSS-4686

Comment: Thanks Tim - I updated the `cmd` in ` vi ~/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.2/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.17.1/lib/vagrant-vbguest/installers/centos.rb` and it works fine. I will accept the answer if you do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a new version of vagrant-vbguest which fixes the issue (0.17.2) - also, there is also a new version of minidcos which includes a doctor check that at least this version is installed.

Comment: `vagrant plugin update vagrant-vbguest` is what I ran, presently it updated my copy to 0.19.0. This helped me get past the problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Tim Harper in comment, I have updated the file `~/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.2/gems/vagrant-vbguest-0.17.1/lib/vagrant-vbguest/installers/centos.rb`.

In that file I have commented out:

`` # cmd = "yum install -y kernel-devel-`uname -r` --enablerepo=C#{rel}-base --enablerepo=C#{rel}-updates" ``

and added:

`` cmd = "yum install -y kernel-devel-`uname -r` --enablerepo=C*-base --enablerepo=C*-updates" ``

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new version of vagrant-vbguest which fixes the issue (0.17.2).
There is also a new version of minidcos which includes a doctor check that at least this version is installed.